# On this night vs In this night

Tags: prepositions

In this night of wonder or On this night of wonder, which is correct?

The full context is

> God from heav’nly splendour
> Comes to earth below;
> *In/On* this night of wonder,
> The world is all aglow.

Answer (score 1):

**Both** are correct.

Without further context, it's difficult to be more specific, but *in* is more "immediate" than *on.*

- *In* could be useful where you are immersing the reader in the action;
- *On* might be more appropriate when you are describing things at more of a distance.

"Night of wonder" and "all aglow" suggests a poetic or literary slant to the text, which means the usage suggested above is a lot more fluid and *in* could be used instead of *on* (but probably not the other way round).

Comment: Yes it’s for a poem “God from heav’nly splendour, Comes to earth below, In this night of wonder, World is all aglow”

Comment: Personally, I would use _on this/that night_ when referring to a particular date, and _in_ when referring to something that happened during the night (as in Sherlock Holmes' 'curious incident of the dog in the night-time').

Comment: For me it’s like ‘during the night or during this night’. Should I go ahead with ‘in’?

Comment: Comments are not for discussion. If you would like to add to your question, please edit it, preferably **without invalidating existing answers** where they are applicable to the original question. However, "Do you think..." or "Should I..." are inherently opinion-based. Please don't add that. You need to consider the answer(s) you have and make up your own mind. [And it's poetry: it's entirely up to you anyway.]

Answer (score -1):

"On" for days and dates,(On Tuesday, on the 17th, on our honeymoon) "in" for general periods of time(in a week, in april, in 2021,)

Comment: So which should be used in the given example?